# reshape pandas data frame: duplicated rows to columns, with textual data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe like this:

```
INDEX_COL                col1
A                        Random Text 
B                        Some more random text
C                        more stuff
A                        Blah
B                        Blah, Blah
C                        Yet more stuff
A                        erm
B                        yup
C                        whatever
```

What I need is it reformed into new columns and stacked/grouped by values in col_1.   So something like this:

```
A                               B                              C
Random Text                     Some more random text          more stuff
Blah                            Blah, Blah                     Yet more stuff
erm                             yup                            whatever
```

I've reviewed [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe) but all of the examples work with numerical data and this is a use case that involves textual data, so aggregation appears to be not an option (but it was - see accepted answer below)

I've tried the following:

Pivot - but all the examples I've seen involve numerical values with aggregate functions.  This is reshaping non-numerical data

I get that index=INDEX COL, and columns= 'col1', but values?  add a numerical column, pivot and then drop the numberical columns created?  Feels like trying for forced pivot to do something it was never meant to do.

Unstack - but this seems to convert the df into a new df with a single value index of 'b'

`unstack(level=0)`

I've even considered slicing the data frame by index into separate dataframes and the concatinating them, but the mismatched indexes result in NaN appearing like a checkerboard.  Also this feels like an fugly solution.

I've tried dropping the index_col, with Col1=['A,B,C'] and col2= the random text, but the new integer index comes along and spoils the fun.

Any suggestions or thoughts in which direction I should go with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `agg(list)` and then `explode` the whole dataframe:

```
output =  df.groupby('INDEX_COL').agg(list).T.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

output:

```
INDEX_COL   A          B                        C
col1    Random Text   Some more random text   more stuff
col1    Blah          Blah, Blah         Yet more stuff
col1    erm              yup               whatever
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've chosen this solution as it's the one that is the easiest to read and follow, with chained functions setting out the  sequence of actions clearly.  What I was missing in my earlier attempts was not knowing that a textual list can be aggregated and that the resulting datatype was Series.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, using [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
(df.pivot_table(columns='INDEX_COL', values='col1', aggfunc=list)
 .pipe(lambda d: d.explode(d.columns.tolist()))
 .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
INDEX_COL            A                      B               C
0          Random Text  Some more random text      more stuff
1                 Blah             Blah, Blah  Yet more stuff
2                  erm                    yup        whatever
```